# Force gcc to use syscalls

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

So I am currently learning assembly language (`AT&T` syntax). We all know that `gcc` has an option to generate assembly code from C code with `-S` argument. Now, I would like to look at some code, how it looks in assembly. The problem is, on laboratories we compile it with `as+ld`, and as for now, we cannot use C libraries. So for example we cannot use printf. We should do it by syscalls (32 bit is enough). And now I have this code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    int c = a + b;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

This is simple code, so I know how it will look with syscalls. But if I have some more complicated code, I don't want to mess around and replace every `call printf` and modify other registers, cuz `gcc` generated code for printf, and I should have it with syscalls. So can I somehow make `gcc` generate assembly code with syscalls (for example for I/O (console, files)), not with C libs?

Comment: GCC doesn't know how to generate code for `printf` except by making a call to the C library function.

Comment: Hmm, okay. So maybe if I insert some assembly code in `C` instead of `printf`, then it will work...

Comment: The section 2 of the manual is [dedicated to system calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html) which enumerates the POSIX [wrappers around the syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#The_library_as_an_intermediary). You can use those for starting. The calling convention will be different but that should be manageable.

Comment: Syscalls are OS specific. What OS do you use?

Comment: Linux, 64bit, but have to compile for 32bit

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux there exist the macro family `_syscallX` to generate a syscall where the X names the number of parameters. It is marked as obsolete, but IMHO still working. E.g., the following code should work (not tested here):

```
_syscall3(int,syswrite,int,handle,char*,str,int len);
// ---

char str[]="Hello, world!\n";
// file handle 1 is stdout
syswrite(1,str,14);
```